# WPF DatePicker: What is the best?

Tags: wpf

I need a Datepicker for a WPF application. What is considered to be the best one?

Comment: What's really odd is, why isn't there one in the default control toolkit?

Comment: In .NET 4 it's going to be included in the .NET base class library.

Comment: to be fair (and more relevant for this question) I think you should change the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### There is also the [WPF Tool Kit](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf) which has a DatePicker/Calendar control

(i added emphasis because this is the answer)

Comment: I'm using this one - from a brief try it seems to do what I want. And it's the official toolkit, so I'm going with it.

Comment: Don't forget that it's going to be a part of the official .NET base class in version 4.

Answer (score 12):

This is an old question, but for the record I want to point out that **this control is included with .NET 4**.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used Marlon's, but I have used [Kevin Moore's](http://j832.com/bagotricks/). At the time I used it, there were a number of bugs I had to [work around](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2007/07/wpf-and-date-entry.html). Other than those issues, it did seem to work well enough.

Comment: Does anyone else find it odd that neither of these controls have simple working demos on the blog post? The whole point of Silverlight is easy deployment, but these authors couldn't take the time to put a demo on their blog? Something fishy about that community...

Comment: I do WPF but I wouldn't touch Silverlight with a 100 foot pole. They could put up a ClickOnce app as a demo though.

Comment: Note that Scott's answer of WPF Toolkit is a better solution now that it has been released. I've used it with good success.

Comment: Also don't forget that it's (the WPF Toolkit) going to be a part of the official .NET base class in version 4.

Answer (score 1):

If you pay [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf.aspx) has a great DatePicker and Calender

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of using this one: [Marlon Grech Date Picker](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2007/09/11/wpf-datepicker/).