# DateTimePicker Control in WPF

Tags: wpf, datetimepicker

I am searching for a DateTimePicker control which can be used as a textbox so user can enter date/time data at will (ie; type in the string **"11/09/2008 12:30:00")** or can select date/time from a drop down list that contains a calendar/time box (what i meant is that this control can provide both options as mentioned). If you have found such a flexible control (and free too) please give me the needed information to obtain it.

Comment: I've resolved my problem by using the Winform's DateTimePicker control. I added the System.Windows.Forms ref and used WindowsFormHost when refering to the control in my xaml. For date entry slot, i set Format=Short, AllowDrop=True. For time entry slot, Format=Time, ShowUpDown=True.

Answer (score 1):

There's the [DatePicker and Calendar controls](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-calendar-datepicker-walkthrough.aspx) from the WPF team, but I don't believe they handle times (as in your example) - just dates. Worth a look though.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [WPF Date Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327/wpf-datepicker-what-is-the-best) question.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

[Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) has a decent DateTimePicker control but it's not free.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for anyone interested... Extended WPF Toolkit™ Community Edition is free (also has a premium option) and contains a [DateTimePicker](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimePicker) which I have found to be very useful in WPF!

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure whether you don't want to use JQuery or not aware of it. But here is this free/open source [date time picker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker) from JQuery which does exactly what you are looking for, plus lot more.

Comment: WPF is not a webpage, therefore jQuery can't be used